# Datepicker displaying wrong day when hosted in Azure

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, azure, jquery-ui-datepicker

When I debug the website locally it's working fine, however, the website hosted in Azure is displaying yesterday's date. The Azure server is located in my own timezone.

I suspect it's using the UTC time, but shouldn't it just use the local workstation time since it's JavaScript?.

I've configured my JQuery UI datepicker like this:

```
var today = new Date();
$('.datepick').each(function () {
    $(this).datepicker(
    {
        required: true,
        message: "This is a required field",
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        minDate: today,
        maxDate: addDays(today, 3)
    });
});
```

My `today` object is showing the current datetime, as expected.

[image: Debugger]

However, the interface is showing yesterday's date:

[image: Datepicker UI]

Comment: The server will be UTC. Is there any round-trip to the server? You often find that the time zone info is lost either to or from the server, so that after a round trip you see yesterday's date.

Comment: Don't see any round-trips... The page is just being loaded and the datepicker is initialized (in the browser as far as I know?).

Comment: I'd use the network tools in the browser to check, just to be sure. It's the most logical explanation. If not then I'm perplexed :)

Comment: Yeah, I used the IE11 dev tools to check for connections to the server. There's just one where it's requesting the page.

Comment: That's very odd. Sorry I couldn't help and good luck.

Comment: @Nicholas Azure should not be even the concern this is being executed in browser. I tried your code here http://jsfiddle.net/mxv4sc5p/ and its working as expected

Comment: It works fine when I run my code from Visual Studio, it just occurs when deployed on the server.

Comment: Are you RDP'd into the VM where this code is running? If so then it will display UTC.

Comment: No, I'm not. Just running the website in my browser on my PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is needed, but I solved it using `setDate`.

```
var today = new Date();
$('.datepick').each(function () {
    $(this).datepicker(
    {
        required: true,
        message: "This is a required field",
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        minDate: today,
        maxDate: addDays(today, 3)
    });
    $(this).datepicker("setDate", today);
});
```